# Update field setting value using getFieldByHandle

Tags: plugin-development, field, image, limit

I need to update the limit setting for Images allowed to be empty, so as to allow for no limit. How do I go about updating the 'limit' setting?

```
$fieldsService = Craft::$app->getFields();
$field = $fieldsService->getFieldByHandle('productImages');
// Need to update 'limit' to equal '' (currently limited to '5')
// Then save the new setting
$fieldsService->saveField($field);
```

***SOLUTION***

I was able to accomplish this by using `setAttributes` and setting the second argument `$safeOnly` to `false`

```
$field->setAttributes([
    'limit' => ''
],false);
```

Comment: `$field->limit = '' ` does the trick as well

Comment: @Hector can you add what worked for you as an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MY SOLUTION

Use `setAttributes` and set the second argument `$safeOnly` to false

```
$fieldsService = Craft::$app->getFields();
$field = $fieldsService->getFieldByHandle('productImages');
// Update 'limit' value to be empty in order to accept as many images as needed
$field->setAttributes([
    'limit' => ''
],false);
$fieldsService->saveField($field);
```